# Does -moz-win-borderless-glass work?

Tags: javascript, firefox, css

So, [I found out that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-appearance) in Firefox, I can make an element to have Windows Aero effect using CSS's `-moz-appearance`. However, it doesn't seem to work. When I click on the button, nothing happened. Am I doing anything wrong there? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/XNN5g/

Comment: Most of the option did not work for me, but maybe some only work on specific elements?

Comment: Know this is a silly question but you do have Windows Vista or later ye? I have tested other ones and they work fine, just this one seems to be the problem

Comment: Also, there is no demo for this feature in the demo box

Comment: @Lodder - I am using Windows 7, and somebody had been able to make it works: http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1446447988

Comment: ah ok then, glad you got it working

Comment: @Lodder - That's somebody else's... I still can't make it work. Do you have any idea why it won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)

> The appearance property is used to display an element using a
>   platform-native styling based on the users' operating system's theme.

The problem of using the -moz-win-borderless-glass within a website element is that this element will be being composed at least against the background of the chrome element that holds the website contents and by default is white. Thus it won't appear as having a glass style because only an element at the bottom of the composition (including the chrome) can display this behaviour.

You can change the appearance of the chrome elements through an addon such as Stylish, but this is something the user has to install. Chrome elements can have the glass style if you set -moz-appearance property accordingly, including the entire element that holds the website contents.